# What does it mean in the man page of shutdown that Requests that the system be halted after it has been brought down?

Tags: linux, shutdown, man

Today when I was reading the man page of shutdown, it made me confused a lot. Take -H as example. I just could not understand the "after it has been brought down". What does it specify exactly? What is the meaning of "been brought down"?

```
OPTIONS
       -r     Requests that the system be rebooted after it has been brought down.
       -h     Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has been brought down, with the choice as to which left up to the system.
       -H     Requests that the system be halted after it has been brought down.
       -P     Requests that the system be powered off after it has been brought down.
       -c     Cancels a running shutdown.  TIME is not specified with this option, the first argument is MESSAGE.
       -k     Only send out the warning messages and disable logins, do not actually bring the system down.
```

Answer (score 1):

The "been brought down" is referring to the shutdown processes.  The shutdown command triggers a run level which tells all of the configured services to shutdown so the system can be safely rebooted, halted, etc.  "Brought down" is referring to that process of stopping and killing running processes.